# Use drush to download drupal core files directly into directory rather than subdirectory

Tags: drush, installation

When you use `drush dl` normally, it will download drupal into a subdirectory ie: *drupal-7.16*

I would like to skip creating the subdirectory and just install the drupal root directory files into the pwd or destination directory.  ie: */var/www/install.php*

**Can this be done with drush commands?**

Other shell workarounds also welcome and will be considered for answer status if this is impossible with drush.

Comment: Be aware that this is an insecure setup.  Check some of the comments below for an explanation of a more secure way to do this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
drush dl drupal --destination=/var --drupal-project-rename=www
```

Comment: Can you expand on how this is different than the other answers?

Comment: MPD: It's different because it actually comes closer to answering the question than Greg's answer.

Comment: Thanks lunitin! It IS the solution, but to correctly solve the question it would have to be. --destination=/var --drupal-project-rename=www

Answer (score 1):

Drush usually creates a sub directory, But you can easily copy all the files from this sub directory "/var/www/drupal-7.12" to its upper folder "/var/www/" with this code

```
mv * .* ..
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the name of the destination folder to download Drupal into via the --destination parameter.  For example:

```
$ cd /var
$ drush dl drupal --destination=www
```

**Aside:** Note that it's probably better to put your site in /var/www/mysite.org rather than directly in /var/www; someday, you might want to put a second site on the same server.

Comment: I would go further, and say put it in /var/www/mysite.org/docroot so you can put your private directory in /var/www/mysite.org/private, and make a /var/www/mysite.org/conf for any Apache includes you may need.  Changing all of this after the fact can be a pain.

Comment: FWIW, I use the same structure recommended by MPD in all of my Drupal sites.

Comment: --destination creates the subdirectory still.  The rest is not relevant to the question.